# What stops the set $\{a:P(\xi =a)>0)$ from being uncountable? where $\int |\xi |dP <\infty$

Tags: probability-theory

Assume that $(\Omega,\mathcal F, P) $ is some probability space and that $\xi $ is a real-valued integrable random variable on $\Omega $

> My question is: What stops the set $\{a:P(\xi =a)>0)$ from being uncountable?

I'm not able to motivate this. Of course the suspicion is that the measure of this set would be greater than one, but then I'm not sure how to measure it since it is an uncountable union.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't even need the condition $\int |\xi| dP <\infty$. For any $n$ the interval $[-n,n]$ can have at most $n$ points $a_1,a_2,..,a_n$ with $P(\xi=a_i) >\frac  1n$ for each $i$. [ Because if we had $n+1$ such points $a_1,a_2,..,a_{n+1}$ the $ P(\xi \in \{a_1,a_2,..,a_n\}) \geq \frac {n+1} n>1$ which is a contradiction. Now take the union of all these finite sets over $n$ to get a countable set such that $P(\xi =a)=0$ whenever $a$ is not in this countable set.